# How to perform a rotation of field of view using only mirrors/lenses?

Tags: optics, microscopy

[image: Setup]

How does one rotate a "microscope" fluorescence image on the detector using only lenses and mirrors in the set-up shown above? I am trying to do ray tracing to understand how to do this, but lenses are typically spherically symmetric, and mirrors only give translation in x,y. By rotation, I mean an x-y translation that is radially dependent.

Comment: Google search for "optical image rotation" gives as first entry: "￼￼Image rotation devices - a comparative survey" by D. W. SWIFT. Edmund optics sells these prisms at http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/prisms/image-rotation-prisms/. That's the second Google hit. Shall we call this insufficient effort? I think so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware that prisms can do such a rotation - I was asking if only mirrors could do such a transformation. I suppose to the answer to my question is "no" given your response.

Comment: Why couldn't you do with mirrors what can be done with prisms? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92486/how-to-optically-rotate-images-in-small-increments-for-eyeglasses. Is that what you are "looking" for?

Comment: "Image rotation in plane-mirror optical systems". James C. DeBruin ; David B. Johnson

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific: the image you see above is the right arm of an interferometric system. I refrain from using transmissive prisms because variations in design lead to phase fluctuations in both arms. Here is a poorly constructed schematic (sorry): http://imgur.com/PHNhR90

When I am imaging the same exact thing by both sides, the images are off by a small rotation (~5 degrees). I'm not sure how this rises from just having mirrors and lenses.

Comment: Yes, you should have been more specific and the theory of how image rotation arises is, if I am not mistaken and based on the abstract, detailed in the last paper. For some reason you seem to have gotten this idea that mirrors just can't rotate images, when a simple experiment with two or three mirrors should have proven to you the opposite.

Comment: I've observed that mirrors can rotate images, but I can't explain how using simple ray tracing arguments. I will look into the DeBruin paper you listed.

Answer (score 1):

This rotation you observed arises when the axis about the mirrors are rotated is not perfectly normal to the plane of your image. Prisms do with internal reflection what your mirrors do with "just" reflection. The only difference is that the light doesn't have to traverse a medium of different refractive index.